# how to write subquery and use "In" Clause in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I use In clause in Hive 
I want to write something like this in Hive
  select x from y where y.z in (select distinct z from y) order by x;
But I am not finding any way of doing it..
I tried In clause in Hive 0.7 it was throwing error, Also I tried Find_in_Set ..
using find_in_set(y.z,subquery).. but the job is getting failed.

I want to do this on Hive. Please help me if anybody knows how to do this in Hive..

Thanks & Regards,
Atul

Comment: Probably this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124635/5238639

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select:

"Hive does not support IN, EXISTS or subqueries in the WHERE clause."

You might want to look at:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-801

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1799

Comment: Hive supports this now as of 0.13

Answer (score 38):

You can use semi join(https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-joins.html):

LEFT SEMI JOIN implements the correlated IN/EXISTS subquery semantics in an efficient way. Since Hive currently does not support IN/EXISTS subqueries, you can rewrite your queries using LEFT SEMI JOIN. The restrictions of using LEFT SEMI JOIN is that the right-hand-side table should only be referenced in the join condition (ON-clause), but not in WHERE- or SELECT-clauses etc.

```
SELECT a.key, a.value
  FROM a
  WHERE a.key in
   (SELECT b.key
    FROM B);
```

can be rewritten to:

```
   SELECT a.key, a.val
   FROM a LEFT SEMI JOIN b on (a.key = b.key)
```

Answer (score 20):

Hive 0.13 now do support  IN/EXISTS in the WHERE-clause .. The issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784 has been resolved after 4 years :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using hive version `0.7.1` and `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN IN ('thisThing','thatThing');`

I tested this on a column type `STRING` so I am not sure if this works universally on all data types since I noticed like Wawrzyniec mentioned above that the Hive Language Manual says that it is not supported and to instead use `LEFT SEMI JOIN` but it worked fine in my test.

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports perfectly the IN ... it does not support the subquery in the WHERE clause

there is an open feature ticket from Facebook engineers since 4 years...
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784?focusedCommentId=13579059

Answer (score 0):

assume `table t1(id,name)` and `table t2(id,name)`

listing only those ids from `t1` that exists in t2(basically `IN` clause)

```
hive>select a.id from t1 a left semi join t2 b on (a.id=b.id);
```

listing only those ids from `t1` that exists only in `t1` but not in t2(basically `NOT IN` clause)

```
hive>select a.id from t1 a left outer join t2 b on(a.id=b.id) where b.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does support IN/EXISTS statements since Hive 0.13 with few limitations. Please refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries for more details.