# Why Hive query doesn't support IN/EXIST operator?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I take look at [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)

and recognize Hive query doensn't support IN/EXIST operator and they suggest using LEFT SEMI JOIN as a replacement. Do you know the reason why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reminds me of the questions Eric Lippert gets of the form "Why doesn't C# have Java feature X?"  People don't build a language by starting with another one and removing stuff, they start with nothing and decide what features to implement.

At some point, hive supported neither IN\EXISTS subqueries, nor LEFT SEMI JOIN.  Then, someone [suggested they add LEFT SEMI JOIN](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-870).  Now that that's in the language, it takes away some of the reason for implementing IN\EXISTS subqueries, since the two are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Hive supports in/exist operators but does not support subqueries with in `in` .

As an alternative to that you can use left semi join.

Below is not possible in Hive

```
SELECT a.key, a.value
  FROM a
  WHERE a.key in
   (SELECT b.key
    FROM B);
```

The above can be rewritten using left semi join.

```
SELECT a.key, a.val
   FROM a LEFT SEMI JOIN b on (a.key = b.key)
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677333/how-to-write-subquery-and-use-in-clause-in-hive)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's IN/EXISTS *subqueries* that aren't supported

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Hive seems to support IN operator:

`A IN (val1, val2, ...) TRUE if A is equal to any of the values.`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF