# How can I substitute 'not in' in Hive 0.13 since it is not supported?

Tags: hive

Considering this query:

```
select distinct col1,col2 
from table 
where col1='x' and (col1,col2) not in (select col1,col2 from table1)
order by col1, col2
```

How can I achieve the above query in hive version 0.13 which does not support **not in**

I have tried to use minus, but apparently minus also is not supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive command to execute NOT IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880124/hive-command-to-execute-not-in-clause)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, from review I edit your question to improve title (as a sentence), formatted code for readability and some minor spelling

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select distinct t.col1, t.col2
from table t left outer join table1 t1
    on t.col1 = t1.col1 and t.col2 = t1.col2
where t.col1 = 'x' and
    t1.col1 is null and t1.col2 is null
order by t.col1, t.col2;
```

Explanation: in a left outer join between `table` and `table1`, whenever columns for `table1` are null, it means that the corresponding columns in `table` were `not in` `table1`.

Comment: @javatp - in such cases, you should both upvote the answer and mark it accepted- the person who answers gets some points for his efforts and someone coming to this question also benefits :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its already supported in the version 0.13, but with some limitations, see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause). If you have older version your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16983858/2037229).