# HIVE SQL Subquery in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables with similar fields but the query is failing when I am doing a `SELECT` subquery in a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT foo 
FROM   bar
WHERE  fizz IN (SELECT fizz FROM fuzz)
```

I deleted the `error.log` from AWS but the error was something to the extent that HIVE did not recognize the `SELECT`.

How do I need to restructure this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Subqueries in the WHERE Clause section of the [HIVE Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries):

```
SELECT b.foo FROM bar b WHERE b.fizz IN (SELECT f.fizz FROM fuzz f)
```

Comment: Basically, you have columns with the same name and it was confused which column to return.

Comment: @user2715877 If this worked for you, please select it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has problems with subquery in the WHERE clause use a JOIN

```
SELECT foo FROM bar 
JOIN fuzz
ON bar.fizz=fuzz.fizz
```

Comment: You've switch table names with column names ;-)

Comment: This is another way of selecting, but doesn't answer his question. There are many legitimate instances to use a select statement in a where clause.

Comment: @MylesBaker How do I need to restructure the query is the question.If you don`t like competition just say so.

Comment: @MylesBaker The question is about restructuring the query in order to fix the error, this can be a solution and in term of performance the use of jointure instead of subquery is much better

Comment: @Mihai You're correct. I misread his question, I'm sorry. And I'm fine with the competition! But I did post first! :P

Answer (score -1):

Hive does not support IN, EXISTS or subqueries in the WHERE clause. Go for a cross join...